# Nonprofit for religious blog?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, non-profit

If I write a religious blog (specifically with posts explaining the meaning of Bible verses, similar to sermons but written instead of spoken), could I start a 501c3 to run the site, donate money to the 501c3 to pay for Web hosting, and write off the donations on my tax return?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://money.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BlueDogRanch
 This question is clearly on-topic here on Law.se. That it might also be on-topic on a different SE site is not a valid reason to close it here. The OP chose to post it here, and that choice should be honored unless it is clearly off-topic here. If someone wants to post a comment advising the OP that better answers might be obtained on a different site, that would be fine IMO.

Comment: Yes, very obviously on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IRS page ["Exemption Requirements - 501(c)(3) Organizations"](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/charitable-organizations/exemption-requirements-501c3-organizations) describes the basic requirements for an organization to qualify as tax-exempt under section 501(c)(3). The linked page ["Application Process"](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/application-process) starts a sequence walking a potential applicant throgh the requirements.

Key requirements are:

- **Form**: a 501(c)(3) organization must be a trust, a corporation, or an association;
- **Purpose**: a 501(c)(3) organization must have an exempt purpose. "Advancement of religion" is one acceptable purpose;
- **Benefits**: a 501(c)(3) organization must not have any of its funds be for the benefit of any shareholder, member or private individual, and must not serve private intersts (as the IRS defiens that term). See https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/charitable-organizations/inurement-private-benefit-charitable-organizations for more detail.

Note that an application must be signed and filed with information about the organization. An annual filing is required thereafter.

Note also that under current US Federal tax law, only contributions in excess of 10% of a taxpayer's Adjusted Gross income (AGI) may be deducted. This is a somewhat recent change, previously the limit was much lower (2.5% of AGI at one time). This means that many people will see little or no tax benefit unless they contribute a fairly sizable amount. But one would be wise to consult one's tax advisor or one's past year tax return to see what the AGI was, and learn what amount of deduction is likely in future years. Of course, Congress can change the tax laws at any time.

Note also that deductions from income only save a taxpayer his or her marginal rate on taxation. That is, if the taxpayer is in a 15% bracket, a contribution of $100 **more** than the AGI threshold will save the taxpayer $15. Contributions up to and including the AGI threshold will have no effect on the tax owed.

Once money is contributed to a 501(c)(3) organization  it may not be simply taken back, even if the contributor is also the operator of the organization.

Comment: Thank you! So I can't write off donations that are less than 10% of my income? I'm a dependent of someone else, and my income last year was only a few hundred dollars, so it might actually be worth doing.

Comment: Note, your AGI is significantly different from your gross income, but exactly how depends on your individual tax situation. If your income is only "a few hundred" then your tax liability must be fairly small. You can't possibly do better than reduce your tax to zero. would that sum be worth costs of setting up such an entity, and the trouble of an additional annual tax failing? You would need to decide that.

Comment: oh yeah, i hadn't thought of the costs of setting up the nonprofit. It definitely won't be worth the cost. Thank you!